# Cannot get value of ember select object from component

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember, so another Ember question - I have a template which contains a form.  The form contains two select objects and a submit button.  The select objects are components.  What I'm having trouble with is getting the selected value of the select objects when the submit button is clicked.  Here is the template code for one of the select objects:

```
{{
  view
  content=relationshipTypes
  value=selectedRelationshipType
  selection=selectedRelationshipType
  prompt="Select Relationship Type..."
}}
```

Here is the component.js code for the select object:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: 'btn-group relationship-type-select'.w(),
  change: function(event) {
    var typeSelected = this.get('selectedRelationshipType');
    this.set('selectedRelationshipType', typeSelected);
  }
});
```

And in the route.js for the template that contains the submit button (with an action for createRelationship):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('people.show').get('entityRelationships');
  },
  setupController(controller) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    controller.set('person', this.modelFor('people.show'));
  },
  actions: {
    relationshipEntityTypeSelected: function(type) {
      console.log("IN RELATIONSHIPENTITYTYPESELECTED.TYPE");
      this.set('selectedRelationshipType');
    },
    createRelationship: function() {
      var fromEmfId = this.modelFor('people.show').id
      console.log("FROM EMF ID==>" + fromEmfId);
      var toEmfId = "";
      var relationshipType = this.get('selectedRelationshipType');
      console.log("RELATIONSHIP-TYPE==>" + relationshipType);
    }
  }
});
```

So all I want is to be able to get the selected relationship type in the createRelationship function, but I have been unable to do it so far.  If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Unfortunately, that site is blocked by my company's internet filters.  I'd have to try later at home.

Answer (score 0):

In select component remove `selection=selectedRelationshipType` and keep only `value=selectedRelationshipType` if your relationshipTypes is just an array with values. Then in your controller you can type `this.get('selectedRelationshipType')` in order to get selected value.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, that did not work.  For this app that I inherited, the controller is a level up, so the actions are in a route.  In addition, I forgot to add that the template that uses the component calls it like this:  {{relationship-type-select}}.  That seems to simple to me.  Thanks again for your helpl.

Comment: Also, the route is on the same level as the template which calls the component, so they should have the same context.

Comment: if i get it right then you should bubble up an action from component to your route. So call your component: `{{relationship-type-select action=relationshipEntityTypeSelected}}`. `relationshipEntityTypeSelected` is your route action. Then from inside your component call `this.sendAction(this.get('selectedRelationshipType'))` to send the action with the selected value up to route. Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: It does make sense.  I'm learning as I go.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: One question (for now): in my route I have an action of relationshipEntityTypeSelected.  What should go in there?  This is the code, but I don't see the action being triggered when I change the select value.

    actions: {
 relationshipEntityTypeSelected: function(type) {
   this.set('selectedRelationshipType', type);
 }

Comment: You can have an observer on selectRelationshipType which is bind with select value. Then put this.sendAction(this.get('selectRelationshipType')) inside your observer. This way your action will send up to your route whenever you select a new option for your select component.